# What is the best way to store previous response from an API and compare with new response in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a database whose values are exposed via a microservice API to Nodejs server, further utilised by reactjs UI. In the Nodejs middleware, I perform some operations and see whether the db API respone values are eligible to be sent to UI or not. Now in UI I'm building a dashboard which will show a "Latest" indicator to those values which the user sees now for first time. How can I work on this logic in UI or middleware?

1 approach I've tried is-
Send a flag from middleware that isIndicator= true or not. I use moment library and see if the day value added in db and the current day, the difference between them is <5(it should be displayed only for 5 days), then set flag as true else false.

```
const d1=moment ().utc()
const d2=moment (dateAdded).utc()
const d=d1.diff(d2);
```

But this will fail if the value in db is there for long and recently is eligible for UI display.

Can someone please help me build the logic?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are doing. I think you might need to clarify more, add some examples perhaps. Evidently dates are involved here but its unclear what makes something ineligible, latest etc,

Comment: Sorry for that, I can give an example. Let's say 10 values exists in db, out of which yesterday there were 5 values from DB that were eligible for UI display and was shown to user.(Eligibility has it's own rules, eg value.code===076,etc.). Today 6 values are now eligible to display on UI, so I send them for user display. I need to add a word *Latest* to the 6th value so that user knows it's added newly, and continue displaying it only till 5days since it first appeared on UI for user. How can I do that?

Comment: #1 when you said "Nodejs middleware" Do you mean "your microservice" ? #2 What do you mean by "user sees now for first time" ? #3 What kind of data are you storing? #4 Do you need to control the time the user entered the system or access to some option? #5 Is this a kind of audit system?

Comment: @JRichardsz sure I can answer some questions. #1, it's the typical client server Architecture where Nodejs serves as server. #2 You can take example how news bulletin works, some stories are marked as Breaking news, after sometime it disappears. #3 I'm not storing data anywhere, just send the API response which is JSON format #4 yup #5 nope, kind of News bulletin system

Comment: OK, so I'm imagining I get a list of something like news articles, and then when I fetch the current list of news articles you want to mark the news articles that I haven't seen before as "NEW" to me.  If I refresh my page are they immediately not new any more?  What makes something _not new_?  One could imagine the client (browser) doing this work itself based on an unchanging "date added" field on each item on the server.  That way the data from the server is the same regardless of the state of the client requesting the data.

Comment: This reminds me of how we shouldn't store "age" in a database, but rather "date of birth".  That way the client can compute age on any date based on that date and the date of birth.

Comment: @Wyck yes you are right. The criteria that makes it not New is 5 days after it's new.

Comment: Please improve your question with these valuable comments. By the time, your **breaking news** sample helped me to understand you.

Comment: How is this breaking news sample is related to the question of compare responses. I think is not required the comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Breaking news scenario

Following your sample :

> some stories are marked as Breaking news, after sometime it disappears

You need to define what turns a story into a "breaking news".

Here some samples:

- User Likes frequency
- Average reading time
- How long does the user stay on the story?
- How many times has it been shared?

If you achieve to store these metadata of a single story in your database, it would be easy to develop an endpoint in your api called `/api/news/breaking` which returns you the breaking news. After some days, the same endpoint will return another news which accomplish the requirements.

In this approach, you don't need to compare responses. You just need to store metadata of your stories and its interactions with the user.

### Your scenario

> show a "Latest" indicator to those values which the user sees now for first time

If user with id **jane_doe** enter to the react web and needs to access to some entities which are in the database, using your api, it would be easy to store that in your database:

- jane_doe `>` first attempt to retrieve entities

If the same user, needs to retrieve the same entity, with the previous data, you are capable of determine if these entities were already showed to the user.

In this case, comparison between responses are not required.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to store this information on your server for any other use case, and you can tolerate the "latest" indicator showing up per-browser (i.e. it shows up once on desktop Chrome, another time on a mobile browser, for the same data), then one option is for clients to keep track of their last viewed timestamp in the browser's `localStorage`:

```js
// Get the last timestamp viewed by the user, or 0 if the user hasn't
// viewed anything yet.
const lastViewedTimestamp = Number(localStorage['lastViewedTimestamp'] || 0);
// Assuming your node server returns data in JSON format,
// fetch the data as JSON.
const response = await fetch('/your/data').then(response => response.json());
// Parse the response timestamp into UTC milliseconds since epoch, if needed.
const currentTimestamp = moment(response.date).utc().milliseconds();
// Show the "latest" indicator if the data is newer than the last data viewed
// by the user.
const isLatest = currentTimestamp > lastViewedTimestamp;
// Persist the last viewed timestamp to localStorage.
localStorage['lastViewedTimestamp'] = currentTimestamp;
```

Then, if users refresh the page, or even exit the browser and then re-open the browser, they should not see the "latest" indicator as long as the returned data is not newer than the last data that was fetched.

More on `localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: can you explain how the lastViewedTimestamp part? I do get server response in json but what's  (localStorage['lastViewedTimestamp'])?

Comment: `localStorage` is a special object that persists across page loads, even if you close the browser and re-open. So when you update `localStorage['lastViewedTimestamp']` in the last line, you will see that value on the next page load. Try it out: `localStorage['foo'] = 'bar'`, then refresh the page, then `alert(localStorage['foo'])`

Comment: I added a link to MDN docs which explain how `localStorage` works better than I could.

Comment: Yes but local storage would persist only till application lifetime right? What if a user visits the website after 2-3 days with all cache cleared?

Comment: In my experience, it is very rare for local storage to actually get cleared. Clearing your browser cache does not clear local storage. In Chrome, you have to specifically delete all site data via the settings page, in order to clear local storage.

Comment: However, if this is a high-stakes sort of thing (like a bank, or something like that) and you cannot tolerate users occasionally seeing "latest" when the data is in fact not the latest -- I would not rely on `localStorage`. Instead, you would want to persist this timestamp in the database, and associate the timestamp with the currently authenticated user ID.